# How can I merge geotiffs with a vrt file?

Tags: gdal

I have heard that I can use a vrt file to merge multiple geotiffs into one?

what is the syntax?

```
gdal_tranlsate -of VRT file1.tif file2.tif file2.tif
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you need to use [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) The instructions on the page are pretty clear, but to save you a mouse click, one of the examples is:

```
gdalbuildvrt doq_index.vrt doq/*.tif
```

Comment: Ah...I see i have gdal 1.6.0. I guess this is only from 1.7.0

Comment: It was compiled by default from 1.6.1 onwards. It's worth biting the bullet and upgrading to 1.9 for the extras as well as a good few bug fixes. An alternative would be to look at the page describing VRTs and construct one by hand. It is then treated as a regular format by the rest of the tools.

Answer (score 4):

More specifically to merge multiple tifs in one directory.

```
gdalbuildvrt out.vrt *.tif

gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs epsg:900913 in.vrt  out.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

gdalbuildvrt will build a virtual vrt file with all your individual .tif files, but if you want to convert the .vrt back into a big single .tif file, you need to use gdal_translate.